# Frozen Planet in Interstellar

Tags: space, interstellar

On the frozen planet in Interstellar, how would the humans be able to take off their helmets inside of Dr. Mann's camp?

Considering the temperature was low enough to turn whatever liquid had formed clouds into a solid strong enough that their ship was pushed off course when they hit one of those "clouds".

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your question is whether the cold outside would have been too much for the internal heating of the spacecraft they were in?

Answer (score 9):

It wasn't a camp, it was a spaceship.  They were in the ship that he landed on the planet.  It was a sealed, climate-controlled environment.